# Why can't XPath locate this element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The HTML code on the website is:

`<img width="32" height="32" alt="Purple - Los Angeles" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/197605/sw/KgCRS1A8aoU.jpg">`

and my code is:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[alt = "Purple - Los Angeles"]').click()`

And it can't find the element.

Comment: please share the code and the website

Comment: Add a driver.implicitly_wait() or it's an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost a "at @ " sign before the attribute. Try this following:

```
//img[@alt = "Purple - Los Angeles"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the @ so:

```
 //img[@alt = ‘Purple - Los Angeles’]
```

But this won’t work either:

```
//img[contains(@alt,’Purple - Los Angeles’)]
```

There’s also a problem with the “” inside the xpath so you better use ‘’ as I did